# Compatibility between Dell Perc H730 and Seagate Constellation 4TB drives?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, seagate

I'm considering the purchase of a refurbished Dell R730xd with Perc H730 controller. Does anyone know if that controller will recognize and work with Seagate Constellation 4TB NL-SAS drives (ST4000NM0023)?  The configuration would be RAID 6.

I realize the drives are not officially listed by Dell as supported drives.  Reading around the net, it is unclear to me to what extent the Dell controller will only work with specific (signed?) drives.  On another system, with a Dell H710, I was able to buy 3rd-party disks and they worked fine, but I have no experience with the newer H730 controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DELL PERC H730 is based on the LSI 3108 Chipset, and since this chipset supports disks larger than 2TB and SAS3 communications I can't see reasons for this controller won't work with those Seagate NL-SAS 4TB discs.

What you should consider is the cabling used on this card, since SAS3 cards uses the new SFF8643 connector.

Comment: I can now confirm this works: I've obtained the disks and installed them in a RAID configuration, and so far it's working flawlessly.

Comment: Also works on the Dell PERC H730P controller, though I've had trouble with Seagate Exos 4TB and 6TB SAS drives not being seen by this controller. The older Constellation and Enterprise range of SAS drives work just fine. Seagate Ironwolf Pro SATA drives in 4TB and 6TB flavours work fine too (but they're not SAS, so performance isn't great).